# with open(file, 'a+') as f is not appending

Tags: python, stderr

I have a function that gets called repetitively and writes error data to a log file via `subprocess`, however, whenever new data is written to the file, the old data is cleared.  So it is not appending any new data with the old data.

I'm doing following:

```
error_file = '\\\\some\\unc\\path\\error.log'

class Node:  
    def __init__(self, path, rev):
        self.path = path
        self.rev = rev

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.path, self.rev))

    def __eq__(self, node):
        return (self.path, self.rev) == (node.path, node.rev)

    def __ne__(self, node):
        return not(self == node)

def get_excluded_nodes(excludes_dir):
    nodes = list()
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(os.path.dirname(excludes_dir)):
       if 'flagged' in files:
          with open(os.path.join(root, 'flagged')) as f:
             for line in f.readlines():
                 try:
                     comps = line.split(' -a')
                     path = comps[0].strip()
                     rev = comps[1].split(':')[0].strip()
                     Nodes.append(Node(path,rev))
                 except:
                     pass
    return nodes

def export_node(node, path=archive_dir):
    with open(error_file, 'a') as f:
        try:
            comps = node.path.split('/')
            if '.' in comps[len(comps)-1]:
                os.makedirs(os.path.join(archive_dir, '/'.join(comps[:-1])))
            else:
                os.makedirs(os.path.join(archive_dir, node.path))

            subprocess.call(['svn', 'export', os.path.join(some_path, node.path), another_path)], stderr=f)
        except:
            pass


def remove_duplicate_nodes(nodes):
   return set(nodes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    all_nodes = get_excluded_nodes(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    nodes = remove_duplicate_nodes(all_nodes)
    for node in nodes:
       export_node(node)
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I tried that as well.  That does the same thing.

Comment: I tried your code (modified just enough to actually run something) and it worked fine.  Are you sure that `my_program` isn't writing characters like `\r` etc to your file that are making the output look wrong when you view it?

Comment: @FatalError `my_program` is actually, `['svn', 'export', some_path, another_path]`

Comment: Time to present your [MCVE]. Actually, that time was 20 mins ago!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit haha I thought what I submitted would be enough and I was missing something simple.  I'll add more details

Comment: A MCVE is required upfront because, by definition, people unable to solve their problem themselves (i.e. people asking questions) aren't qualified to guess at what can and can't be omitted.

Comment: Replace `_` with `)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks, modified.

Comment: Are you sure that the file is being written to each time and that you're checking the right file? May be worthwhile to not use that broad except and/or to do something useful in the except clause, like write out the error, for sake of debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's *still* not an MVCE: it isn't minimal (what's Node for, how does it affect appending to a file?) and it isn't complete (where is `get_excluded_nodes`?). Since it isn't complete, it can't be verifiable either.

*This* is an MVCE with the minimal code that *ought* to do the same thing as your example, and it works fine.

```
import subprocess

def test(filename):
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        subprocess.call(['bash', '-c', 'echo $$ >&2'], stderr=f)

if __name__=='__main__':
    for _ in range(2):
        test('stderr.log')
```

which does exactly what you wanted:

```
$ python stderr.py 
$ cat stderr.log 
344
345

$ python stderr.py 
$ cat stderr.log 
344
345
366
367
```

---

**edit** I see you're on Windows, so strace is probably out. Bad luck, you'll just have to write an actual MVCE instead.

---

Maybe run your original (real, sort-of-working) script under strace, and see what's different. For reference, this script shows:

```
$ strace -f -e trace=open,dup2,lseek,write python stderr.py

open("stderr.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 3
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 28
strace: Process 567 attached
...
[pid   567] dup2(3, 2)                  = 2 # stderr=f
... libc, locale stuff ...
[pid   567] dup2(2, 1)                  = 1 # >&2
[pid   567] write(1, "567\n", 4)        = 4
```

Comment: How are my latest updates?  As I mentioned, I'm sorry I didn't have a complete MVCE because I thought maybe there was something simple that I was doing wrong in just the original snippet.

Comment: Can you run the example given here, unaltered ? Does it work for you ? Next ting is to change the file name to an UNC path as your original code does. Does it still work ?

Comment: There's still loads of non-minimal stuff in there: take it all out and see whether a really minimal example (just the open and a toy sample subprocess call) works. If it does, add one thing back and see if it still misbehaves - maybe svn does something unusual, try `['svn', 'ls']` or something trivial and add details until it stops working again.

Comment: Subversion is definitely doing something strange with `stderr` because in the except block I now write any exception to the same file and that stays, but whenever svn writes an error, the old is replaced by the new, but the data written by the exception is still there

Comment: What happens if you use `subprocess.Popen` with stderr set to `PIPE`, reading the output (and copying it to your file) explicitly in your script?

Comment: Yes... That did it!